# R 'automap' how to create prediction grid to use with AutoKrige (e.g. meuse.grid)?

Tags: r, gis, kriging, gstat, automap

I'm having a lot of difficulty creating a prediction grid (for the new_data argument) to use with the autoKrige function in the automap package.

I've already tried following the steps in this post ([How to subset SpatialGrid using SpatialPolygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962821/how-to-subset-spatialgrid-using-spatialpolygon/22387660#22387660)) but get the following error : 
Error in x@coords[i, , drop = FALSE] : 
  (subscript) logical subscript too long
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

My (limited) understanding is the error relates to there being no non-missing arguments because it is an empty grid. This is fine - all I want is an empty grid constrained by a polygon from a shapefile.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
     shp <-  shapefile("C://path/path/Tobay_Box2.shp")
         shp <-  spTransform (shp,"+proj=utm +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")
         grid <-        GridTopology(cellcentre.offset=c(731888.0,7457552.0),cellsize=c(2,2),cells.dim=c(122,106))
         grid <- SpatialPixelsDataFrame(grid,
                              data=data.frame(id=1:prod(122,106)),
                              proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm +ellps=WGS84 +    datum=WGS84"))
plot(grid)
```

[see dropbox folder 'Grid.png']

```
bound <- shp@polygons
bound <- SpatialPolygons(bound, proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"))
plot(bound)
```

[see dropbox folder 'Boundary plot.png']

```
clip_grid <- grid[!is.na(over(grid, bound)),]
```

No errors or warnings up to this point. But then...

```
plot(clip_grid)

Error in x@coords[i, , drop = FALSE] : 
  (subscript) logical subscript too long
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

or attempting to pass the object clip_grid through autokrige for the new_data argument:

```
PerInkrg <- autoKrige (PerArIn~1, hs1, clip_grid)

Error in predict.gstat(g, newdata = newdata, block = block, nsim = nsim,  : 
  value not allowed for: %s %s newdata empty or only NA's
```

I've had no issues using the non-clipped grid (object = grid).

In a nutshell, I require this [see dropbox folder 'Autokrig plot'] but with the interpolated surfaced constrained (clipped) to the boundary extent of 'Torbay_Box2.shp'

P.S. I attempted to insert images of my plots and links to other posts I've used before asking for help here and a link to my data but as a new user I don't have enough reputation to do this - sorry!

Data and plots can be found on Dropbox.com/sh/yqg20z1ibl3h4aa/AACJnHoEuP-S5fTvAXxsnY1za?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I've now managed to produce an autoKrige [plot] which is masked to the extent of the Torbay_Box2 boundary. However, I never achieved this in the 'conventional' way by creating a prediction grid like meuse.grid.  The result is the same so for now I'm happy but I would still like to do it the conventional way eventually.

Here's how I cheated it:

```
 # Load sample box extent

bx.data <- readOGR (".", "Tobay_Box2")
bx <- spTransform(bx.data,"+proj=utm +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84") #transformsto UTM projection
str(bx)

# Set the boundary extent with that of sample box extent

hs1@bbox <- bx@bbox
#create an empty grid
grd              <- as.data.frame(spsample(hs1, "regular", n=50000))                                                                                                
names(grd)       <- c("X", "Y")
coordinates(grd) <- c("X", "Y")
gridded(grd)     <- TRUE  # Create SpatialPixel object
fullgrid(grd)    <- TRUE  # Create SpatialGrid object

plot(hs1)
plot(grd, pch = ".", add = T)
proj4string(grd) <- proj4string(hs1)
```

I then performed an IDW interpolation using the empty grid as the newdata, converted the output to raster, clipped this to the Torbay_Box2 boundary and then converted this to a SpatialPixelDataFrame which I passed through as the new_data argument for autoKrige:

```
# For PerArIn (% area inhabited) 
#interpolate the grid cells using all points and a power value of 2 

hs1.idw <- gstat::idw(PerArIn ~ 1, hs1, newdata=grd, idp=2.0)



# Convert to raster object then clip to Hollicombe sample box

r       <- raster(hs1.idw)
r.m     <- mask(r, bx)


#Convert and set as prediction grid for Kriging

grd<- rasterToPoints(r.m, spatial=TRUE)
gridded(grd) <- TRUE
grd <- as (grd, "SpatialPixels")

#en voila!
PerInkrg <- autoKrige (PerArIn~1, hs1,grd)
```